# Facebook SDK 3.1: Feed Dialog vs Native dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I've found that the Facebook API had been changed a lot since last year and I have to use a new SDK (3.1 by now) in my apps.

I'm trying to figure out what's the difference between [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/) used before and a new [Native Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-native-dialogs-ios-sdk/). So far I can see that (unlike Feed Dialogs) using Native ones is for IOS 6+ only, and that it uses some new [share sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205) framework.

Could you describe (suggest?) in two words what is the practical purpose (difference, benefits?) of these Native Dialogs with respect to Feed Dialogs?
Perhaps your vision of if it makes sense to complicate the code in order to support [Sharing with Native Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-native-dialogs-ios-sdk/) on IOS6+ devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [native dialog is a feature included in the iOS 6 system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205) to share messages easily with a unified UI for all applications. For this the user must have setup his account in the iOS preferences pane!
Most other stuff is something related to the Facebook SDK and not included in the system.

**Pros of Native Controller:**

- included in the system
- unified user interface
- unified API for Twitter, Facebook and more

**Pros of Facebook SDK:**

- external SDK required
- runs on older systems too
- more functions and more customization

Comment: Thank you, miho (up). I got your point and the direction to go to